# Animation on element doesn't run in Chrome, Opera and IE

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-animations

I have a project which allows users to sort rows in table. On a drop, I assign a class `.dropped` to the dropped element.

```
$(".grammar-input-tbl tbody").sortable({
    items: "tr:not(:last-child)",
    handle: "th",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    cursor: "move",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find("tr").removeClass("dropped");
    },
    // Add class on drop
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item.context).addClass("dropped");
    }
});
```

The class is indeed added to the element. However, I assign this class to the element so that I can run a short animation on the dropped element with keyframes.

```
.dropped {
    border-left-color: rgb(102, 175, 233);
    animation: borderFadeDrop 2400ms 600ms forwards;
}

@keyframes borderFadeDrop {
    from {border-left-color: rgb(102, 175, 233);}
    to {border-left-color: rgba(102, 175, 233, 0);}
}
```

The strange thing is, however, that this works perfectly fine on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lu2t0sa/6) (move rows around by their handle on the left) in Edge and Firefox, **but** it doesn't in Chrome, IE nor Opera.

Comment: If your jQuery is the same in jsFiddle as in your website, then you have to look outside your jQuery, maybe your CSS or as @Sparky mentioned, your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been looking at the wrong places. The problem was, unexplicable, `will-change`. Because I transform the rows on drag-start, I added `will-change: transform;`, but Chrome, IE and Opera don't seem to like it when combining it with an animation. It works fine in Edge, and FF. (Removed prefixes for brevity's sake).

```
tbody tr {
    transition:transform 600ms;
    transform:none;

    border-left:4px solid transparent;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;

    /* Here she is. Remove to allow border fade */
    will-change: transform;
}
.dropped {
    border-left-color:#66afe9;
    animation:borderFadeDrop 2400ms 600ms forwards
}

@keyframes borderFadeDrop {
    from {
        border-left-color:#66afe9
    }
    to {
        border-left-color:rgba(102, 175, 233, 0)
    }
}
```

A basic, cleaned-out, case can be found [here](http://2.%20jQuery%20adds%20the%20class%20%22dropped%22%20to%20the%20dropped%20row%202.%20A%20blue%20left-border%20appears,%20and%20OUGHT%20TO%20fade%20out%20because%20.dropped%20launches%20a%20keyframe%20animation.%20This%20doesn't%20work%20on%20Chrome%20and%20IE,%20assumebly%20also%20not).

- Chromium bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=549153).
- IE bug reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1958739/animation-on-element-wont-work-when-will-change-is-set).

IE bug has been closed for the following reason:

> Hello
>
> Thank you for the feedback. This issue appears to have been fixed in
>   Microsoft Edge. We're not presently working on feature bugs in
>   Internet Explorer outside of security-related issues.
>
> Best Regards, The Microsoft Edge Team

Comment: If your issue was cross-browser all along, then it had nothing to do with jsFiddle.  In a particular browser, if it was broke on your website, then it was broke in the jsFiddle too.

Comment: According to Mozilla, Explorer is "not supported".  See "browser support" section:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: @Sparky Even if it isn't supported, the browser should simply ignore *that* rule. However, IE, Chrome, and Opera simply ignore any animation on the element. That's odd.